# How to mock <AppContenxt.Consumer> in React using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

component which I'm exporting and want to test:

```
export default connectToStore(DefaultComponent);
```

connectToStore **wrapper** around component:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppContext from '../components/context/AppContext';

const connectToStore = Component => props => (
  <AppContext.Consumer>
    {({ state }) => (
      <Component {...props} state={state} />
    )}
  </AppContext.Consumer>
);

export default connectToStore;
```

unit test calling component

```
 it('should render view', () => {
    const wrapper = render(<DefaultComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Error which I get:

> Cannot destructure property `state` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

How do you test a component in general if it has a wrapper around it when being exported? How can I have the state injected hence being present in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppContext value property needs to be mocked:

Solution:

```
  const wrapper = mount(
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          data,
          callbackList: {}
        }}
      >
        <DefaultComponent />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer an alternative that's less complicated from a test perspective, you could have simply included a named export for the component itself as a test harness

```
export { DefaultComponent }
export default connectToStore(DefaultComponent)
```

That way your original test would still stand, you would just need to import as

```
import { DefaultComponent } from './defaultComponent'
```

And the of course when mounting mock the `state` prop provided by your context

```
const wrapper = render(<DefaultComponent state={{ ... }} />);
```